# Attempting to use photo Library on UICollectionViewCell Class

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiimagepickercontroller

So right now I am trying to get the collection view Cells to use the photo library to update photos. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class viewCellVC: UICollectionViewCell, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
@IBOutlet var bookImage: UIImageView!
@IBAction func addImage(_ sender: Any) {
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    self.window?.rootViewController?.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    bookImage.image = image
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


}
```

However, when I attempt to run the code and update the pictures, the simulator fails to open the photo library and I instead get the following error message(doesn't end the app, just fails to run the photo library):

```
2017-08-07 21:35:31.709183-0500 ChuBookElf[2817:66569] Warning: Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController: 0x7f907e0bf800> on <ChuBookElf.ViewController: 0x7f907de072c0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Can somebody tell my what I am doing wrong? I've been on this for hours now.

[For Reference, here is what the collection view cell looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqHlc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you are creating the `imagePicker` in a `UICollectionViewCell`.

You should create the `imagePicker` in the `ViewController` that contains the said `UICollectionView` along with the delegate methods. Then, in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`, set the selected image to the appropriate `collectionViewCell` and `reload` your `collectionView`

Comment: I don't know how to retrieve the image from my UICollectionViewCell to my ViewController though.

Comment: I would recommend looking at some tutorials for swift programming. You'll find a ton on the internet. Or you can download swift programming guides from the AppStore for free.